# Java 8 Streams conversion from iterator

Tags: java, java-8

private void applyQueryConditions(List resultList,
            List finalList) {

```
    ListIterator<NestedCustomerDO50> iterator = resultList.listIterator();
    for (; iterator.hasNext();) {

        NestedCustomerDO50 nestedDo = iterator.next();

        if ('S' == nestedDo.getAttrib8()) {

            for (NestedFirstChildDO50 child : nestedDo.getFirstChildList()) {
                if (("ST2".equals(child.getAttrib18()))
                        || ("ST3".equals(child.getAttrib18()))
                        || ("ST4".equals(child.getAttrib18()) || (!"ST"
                                .equals(child.getAttrib18())))) {
                    if (null != child.getGrandChildList()) {
                        for (NestedGrandChildDO50 grandChild : child
                                .getGrandChildList()) {
                            if ((date.after(grandChild.getAttrib19()) && date
                                    .before(grandChild.getAttrib43()))) {

                                finalList.add(nestedDo);

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I want to convert the following code into Java 8 Streams. But I found difficulties. 
NestedCustomerDO50 is a class which is inherited by NestedFirstChildDO50 which is inherited by NestedGrandChildDO50. Each class contains List of the child class(i.e NestedCustomerDO50 contains List of NestedFirstChildDO50 and NestedFirstChildDO50 contains List of NestedGrandChildDO50). Each class contains 50 attributes(attrib1-atrib50).

```
List<NestedGrandChildDO50> testS = resultList.stream() 
.filter(v1 -> v1.getAttrib8() == 'S') 
.flatMap(value -> value.getFirstChildList().stream()) 
.filter(value -> "ST2".equals(value.getAttrib18()) 
|| "ST3".equals(value.getAttrib18()) || "ST4".equals(value.getAttrib18()) ||!("ST".equals(value.getAttrib18()))) 
.flatMap(value -> value.getGrandChildList().stream()) 
.filter( val2 -> (date.after(val2.getAttrib19())) && (date.before(val2.getAttrib43()))) 
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I get only List of GrandChild. But I want ParentObject List satisfying the conditions. Is there any way to do this. Please explain how to do this with code.

Comment: Please format your code. What exactly do you mean by "But I found difficulties.". Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's the meaning of the empty if clauses? If you want help converting this code to Java 8 Streams, you should at least post a complete code.

Comment: I want to create another method equivalent to this method. Here I get parent object list as input(NestedCustomerDO) and should filter the input and produce filtered output of NestedCustomerDO object list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the filter-method of the Stream-API.

`nestedDO.getFirstChildList().stream().filter(c -> {
    String attr18 = c.getAttrib18();
    ...//your comparison
}).forEach(c -> {
    ...//do something with the matching children
});`

```
resultList.stream().
     filter(nestedDo -> nestedDo.getAttrib8() == 'S').
     filter(nestedDo ->  
         nestedDo.getFirstChildList().stream().anyMatch(c -> 
             ("ST2".equals(c.getAttrib18()) || 
             "ST3".equals(c.getAttrib18()) || 
             "ST4".equals(c.getAttrib18()) || 
             !"ST".equals(c.getAttrib18())) &&
             c.getGrandChildList() != null &&
             c.getGrandChildList().stream().anyMatch(gc -> {
                   date.after(gc.getAttrib19()) &&
                   date.before(gc.getAttrib43())
             }))
         ))).
     forEach(finalList.add(nestedDo));
```

Since your method adds nestedDo multiple times to finalList, i've corrected that. Now every matching nestedDo is only added once.

Comment: I want to create a new method equivalent to this method.

Comment: this was just an example for how to use lambdas

Comment: List<NestedGrandChildDO50> testS = resultList.stream()
      .filter(v1 -> v1.getAttrib8() == 'S')
      .flatMap(value -> value.getFirstChildList().stream())
      .filter(value -> "ST2".equals(value.getAttrib18())
        || "ST3".equals(value.getAttrib18())
        || "ST4".equals(value.getAttrib18())
        || !("ST".equals(value.getAttrib18())))
      .flatMap(value -> value.getGrandChildList().stream())
      .filter(
        val2 -> (date.after(val2.getAttrib19()))
        && (date.before(val2.getAttrib43())))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: should work. well, i don't know what the empty if-statements are supposed to do, but apart from that.

Comment: But the result is of GrandChild List and how I want to covert into ParentObject List.

Comment: ok, what exactly is the method supposed to do? the examplecode doesn't filter anything

Comment: Please see the new code. The method will filter the parentclass object on the basis of its childobject list and grandchildobject list

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll post the solution

Comment: But I found braces is not matched correctly. I tried to correct it but I failed

Comment: What is the use of isPresent and findAny

Comment: findany() returns an Optional containing any element of the stream and isPresent is true, if the Optional holds an element and not null. This is basically a workaround to check if the stream is not empty, since isEmpty() is not provided by the stream API

Comment: @Paul: you don’t need a `.findAny().isPresent()` workaround if the previous step is a `filter` operation. Just use [`anyMatch(predicate)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)…

Comment: @Holger thanks, my bad, i haven't used the streamapi for some time.